# Leopoldt's Conjecture and Congruence Subgroups of Prime Ideal Powers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and let $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ be a nonzero prime ideal in its ring of integers. I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2755697/88291) that the following question is equivalent to (a version of) Leopoldt's conjecture:

> Does every finite-index subgroup $U \subset \mathcal{O}_K^\times$ contain a congruence subgroup of the form
>   $$
> \mathcal{O}_K^\times(\mathfrak{p}^m) := \{ x \in \mathcal{O}_K^\times : x \equiv 1 \text{ mod } \mathfrak{p}^m \}
> $$ 
>   for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

As far as I know, the Leopold conjecture for a number field $K$ and a prime number $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ states that the $p$-adic regulator $R_p$ of $K$ vanishes.

**Question:** Is the above problem open? If so, is it equivalent to Leopoldt's conjecture?

Comment: @Infinity (your link) seems like the person who might like to answer this

Comment: You might consider moving or copying this question to https://mathoverflow.net/ as I believe it is about research-level mathematics.

Comment: I told you on your first flag that there is no reason to migrate the post. Please check for replies before flagging anew. You can ask it there yourself if you want; (Provide links.) Further, while a bounty is open it is not possible to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better to consider the following related problem. Fix a prime $p$ and a number field $K$:

> Does every finite-index subgroup $U \subset \mathcal{O}_K^\times$ *of $p$-power index* contain a congruence subgroup of the form
>   $$
> \mathcal{O}_K^\times(p^m) := \{ x \in \mathcal{O}_K^\times : x \equiv 1 \text{ mod } p^m \}
> $$ 
>   for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

This is **literally the same** as Leopoldt's conjecture as formulated by Iwasawa. (I don't know what the previous answer is talking about when it says the problems are different because  Leopoldt is *arithmetic*.)

Consider this with $U = \mathcal{O}^{\times p}_K$. Then this question becomes:

> if $m$ is big enough, is any unit $u \equiv 1 \bmod p^m$ a $p$th power?

Equivalently, let $U_v$ be the local units for $v | p$, and $E$ the group of global units ($\mathcal{O}^{\times}_K$). I claim the question above is equivalent to:

> is the map $E \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p \rightarrow \prod_{v} (U_v \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p)$ injective?

if this map is not injective, then there is a saturated element $v$ in the kernel. Since the image of $E$ in $E \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p$ is dense, it means that, for any $m$, there is a unit $u_m \in E$ which is equal to $v$ up to an element of $p^m (E \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p) = E^{p^m} \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p$. It follows that $u_m$ is a global unit which is $1 \bmod p^m$ but not a $p$th power.

Conversely, if $u_m$ is a sequence of global units which are $1 \bmod p^m$ but not $p$th powers, then their limit $v \in E \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p$ (which is compact, since it is just a finitely generated $\mathbf{Z}_p$-module) will lie in the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

The formulation of Leopoldt's conjecture as the non vanishing of the $p$-adic regulator is limited to totally real field. The general formulation, for any number field, is due to Iwasawa (I think) in the algebraic part of Iwasawa theory, see e.g. Washington's "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields", §13.1. In short :

Let $E$ be the group of units of a number field $K$, $p$ a fixed prime, $U_v$ the groups of local units at all primes $v$ of $K$ above $p$. The natural injection of $E$ into $\prod U_v$ induces a map $E \otimes \mathbf Z_p \to \prod U_v \otimes \mathbf Z_p$. Leopoldt's conjecture: this map is injective. For abelian $K$, this has been proved by Brumer, using $p$-adic transcendental methods. The general case is still a conjecture. In spite of the apparent parenthood with the congruence subgroup theorem given in your link, the two problems are different, at least because Leopoldt's singles out a prime $p$, hence is *arithmetic* in nature.

Comment: What is the group structure of the global units $E=\{x \in \mathcal{O}_K^{\times}~:~x \equiv 1~(\text{mod}~\mathfrak{p}^m)\},~ m \geq 1$ ?